# MySQL Full Group by

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, count

Since my web-host has updated the MySQL server version, my old SQL Query is not working anymore:

```
select COUNT(ID) AS Anzahl, 
       DAY(STR_TO_DATE(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d')) AS Datum 
from `leads` 
where `created_at` >= 2018-02-01 
      and `created_at` <= 2018-02-15 
      and `shopID` = 20 
group by DAY(created_at) 
order by DAY(created_at) asc
```

That means, I have to create a full group by query. I already have read this [article](https://blog.gabriela.io/2016/03/03/group-by-are-you-sure-you-know-it/) but I don't really get it.

> I should name all columns which are unique

Thats what I don't get. If I want to count the ID, I cannot create a group by ID query because in this case my count would always be `1`. Could anybody please explain to me how full group by works and how my statement would like with a full group by statement?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same expression in the `select` as in the `group by`:

```
select COUNT(ID) AS Anzahl, DAY(created_at) AS Datum
from `leads` l
where `created_at` >= '2018-02-01' and
      `created_at` <= '2018-02-15' and
      `shopID` = 20
group by DAY(created_at)
order by DAY(created_at) asc;
```

You also need single quotes around the date constants.

Comment: I don't see the differents except the STR_TO_DATE... why cannot I use it?

Comment: Hmmm . . . MySQL should recognize something in that format as a date.  But if you want to use it, then use it in the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your `select` and `group by` columns doesn't match. You should make them same. Try below query:

```
select COUNT(ID) AS Anzahl, 
       DAY(STR_TO_DATE(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d')) AS Datum 
from `leads` 
where `created_at` >= 2018-02-01 
      and `created_at` <= 2018-02-15 
      and `shopID` = 20 
group by Datum 
order by Datum asc
```